# Vuetify Datepicker range get selected dates

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi stackoverflow community,

got a specific vuetify datepicker question - how to get single selected dates if **range** (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#props-range) prop is activated?

Here is my datepicker

```js
      <v-date-picker
        v-model="days"
        :allowed-dates="allowedDates"
        :min="minDate"
        full-width
        range
      ></v-date-picker>
```

My variable "**days**" contains the following value if you use "range" prop: [*startDate*, *endDate*].

Here is an ui example how it actually looks like:

[image]

Has anyone a clue how to get each single day of date range? Important: i use allowed-dates so there are non selectable fields as well.

Thx for your time and help! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    dates: [],
    days: ["monday", "tuesday", "thursday"]
  }),
  computed: {
    dateRangeText () {
      return this.getDaysArray(this.dates[0], this.dates[1])
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getAllowedDates (value) {
      const date = moment(value);
      const day = date.format("dddd").toLowerCase();
      return this.days.includes(day);
    },
    getDaysArray(start, end) {
      for(var arr=[],dt=new Date(start); dt<=new Date(end); dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)) {
        const dateVal = new Date(dt).toISOString().split('T')[0];
        if (this.getAllowedDates(dateVal)) {
          arr.push(dateVal); 
        }
      }
      return arr;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
            <v-date-picker v-model="dates" range :allowed-dates="getAllowedDates"></v-date-picker>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
            <v-text-field v-model="dateRangeText" label="Date range" prepend-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly></v-text-field>
            dateRange: <pre>{{ dateRangeText }}</pre>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```